# How to retrieve the current holdings from ETF's like VTI

Tags: etf, vanguard, edgar

I'm trying to retrieve the up-to-date list of all holdings for an ETF like VTI. There is a list here:

https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/overview/VTI/portfolio-holdings

but it's very hard to actually download the data.

Is there maybe a filing on EDGAR I should look for?

Comment: How often are you wanting to pull the data?

Comment: Perhaps once a week. Not sure how often there are chances published?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my stab a presenting the data I was looking for.

https://chhenning.github.io/vanguard-tracker/VTI.html

It still is very basic and just a proof of concept.

Comment: Are you sure that Vanguard's ToS allows you to pull their data and publish it? I haven't dug into this particular feed but it's pretty common for this type of data to require you to only use personally and not profit from it / publish it for others.

Comment: vanguard is publishing the data [here](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/overview/VTI/portfolio-holdings). I'm not using the data commercially. I'm just a curious investor in VTI etf.

Comment: Please edit this additional detail into your question; it really isn't an Answer.